# Can any of you explain the following Active Record Database in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to understand the correlation of the following Active record pattern with the regular sql language.

```
$get_it = $this -> db -> select('i.*,SUM(o.qty * o.price) AS total')
                            ->from('invoices i, users u,orders o')
                            ->where('u.usr_name',$user)
                            ->where('u.usr_id = i.user_id')
                            ->where('o.invoice_id = i.id')
                            ->group_by('o.invoice_id')
                            ->get();
```

Is anyone can convert it to sql language at least? That would be a great help.

Comment: IMO this query contains a logical error - grouping and selecting like this.

Comment: Actually it works fine, I just wanted to know if this code is written with the sql query.

Comment: You probably use MySQL as actual DB which allows queries like this (in unstrict mode). Other DB engines throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

To print CodeIgniter query use **$this->db->last_query();** it will print in mysql fromat use it after get() method..hope it will help you